# How to code jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://www.tupaki.com/index.php) is my friend's website i asked him about to code the 
 like [this](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2r5glqb.jpg).

Iam working on code with jquery and javascript and with html because iam using it on blogger.

How to get the slider with clickable links on it as the slider looks like on my friends site.

I tried the coding like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider6').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    startSlide: 2,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/master/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<div class="slider6">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A snippet that doesnt demonstrate the problem is useless. You're missing jquery and also whatever slider plugin you're using. Ive edited to add jQuery but I have no clue what plugin you're using.

Comment: Yes, I presume you are missing the plugin, you can download it here http://bxslider.com/ ; and include jQuery as well, of course

Comment: bxslider is good but i need to display multiple images at one time

Comment: Ok, added bxSlider to your snippet

Comment: I've edited it, add bxslider plugin and now it works! (Well, someone re-edited it again)

Comment: can i have slider with multiple images